# html - table row like a link

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, html-table

I can't set my table row as link to something. I can use only css and html. I tried different things from div in row to something another, but still can't make it works.

Answer (score 182, accepted):

You have two ways to do this:

- Using javascript:

  `<tr onclick="document.location = 'links.html';">`
- Using anchors:

  `<tr><td><a href="">text</a></td><td><a href="">text</a></td></tr>`

I made the second work using:

```
table tr td a {
    display:block;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
```

To get rid of the dead space between columns:

```
table tr td {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
}
```

Here is a simple demo of the second example: [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/BF729/)

Comment: Since OP said "only css and html" I assume the accept was for the second answer. Note that if you don't have border=0 you will get a "missing link" gap between the table cells.

Comment: IIRC the table cells just have to be collapsed, but can have a border.

Comment: The <a> tag doesn't allow any other html elements inside it. Then, How can we link a whole table row which has more table data? Something like this: <tr> <a href=""><td>Text</td><td>.....</a></tr>.. We can't have like this ne?

Comment: You have to make a link <a> in every cell <td>. <tr> <td><a>Link Text</a></td> <td><a>Link Text</a></td> </tr>. You can't use one <a> tag for the whole row <tr> without using JavaScript.

Comment: I would recommend using "display:inline-block" instead of block.  With  block display, I found that Chrome was ignoring the "height:100%" and not actually making the entire height of the <td> click-able if there are other items in the same row that have a greater height.  Making it inline-block fixed that issue, and also a possibly related problem with text getting clipped inside the table elements.

Comment: Anchors still has dead space between columns (tested with Google Chrome Version 40.0.2214.115 m)

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution does NOT work when you have elements like images in a cell, like here: http://jsfiddle.net/yu7ugss8/1/

Comment: As [others](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460958/html-table-row-like-a-link#comment18042008_1460974) have said, using onClick interferes with new-tab-opening actions like ctrl+click or scroll wheel clicks. And the second solution doesn't account for gaps caused by table borders. Check out [Greg's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1461024/1601953) for a much more ideal solution.

Comment: Worked. I did add some padding-left in the a-anchor tag so stuff wasn't stuck to the left side. This way it looks nice wo/ any dead space.

Answer (score 55):

I made myself a custom jquery function:

### Html

```
<tr data-href="site.com/whatever">
```

### jQuery

```
$('tr[data-href]').on("click", function() {
    document.location = $(this).data('href');
});
```

Easy and perfect for me. Hopefully it helps you.

(I know OP want CSS and HTML only, but consider jQuery)

## Edit

Agreed with Matt Kantor using data attr. Edited answer above

Comment: That's pretty elegant actually. I wonder if it's considered invalid html by w3c standards.

Comment: I'd use `data-href` or somesuch.

Comment: JSFiddle link leads to 404.

Comment: add class to `<table class='tr_link' >` and give it to `.tr_link{cursor:pointer}` in css for best usage.

Comment: To add the hand effect on hovering, add `tr[data-href] { cursor: pointer }` to your stylesheets

Answer (score 28):

If you're on a browser that supports it you can use CSS to transform the `<a>` into a table row:

```
.table-row { display: table-row; }
.table-cell { display: table-cell; }

<div style="display: table;">
    <a href="..." class="table-row">
        <span class="table-cell">This is a TD... ish...</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Of course, you're limited to not putting block elements inside the `<a>`.
You also can't mix this in with a regular `<table>`

Comment: Great idea, thanks! It seems to work on Opera 8.5/, Firefox 0.8/, IE8, iPhone Simulator/Safari/very old :)

Comment: This should be the technique that developers try to adopt given that CSS tables are supported by all current browsers: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-table  The only trouble is I can't use this with Bootstrap! :'(

Answer (score 14):

If you *have to* use a table, you can put a link into each table cell:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="person1.html">John Smith</a></td>
      <td><a href="person1.html">123 Fake St</a></td>
      <td><a href="person1.html">90210</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="person2.html">Peter Nguyen</a></td>
      <td><a href="person2.html">456 Elm Ave</a></td>
      <td><a href="person2.html">90210</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And make the links fill up the entire cells:

```
table tbody tr td a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

If you are able to use `<div>`s instead of a table, your HTML can be a lot simpler, and you won't get "gaps" in the links, between the table cells:

```
<div class="myTable">
  <a href="person1.html">
    <span>John Smith</span>
    <span>123 Fake St</span>
    <span>90210</span>
  </a>
  <a href="person2.html">
    <span>Peter Nguyen</span>
    <span>456 Elm Ave</span>
    <span>90210</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS that goes with the `<div>` method:

```
.myTable {
  display: table;
}
.myTable a {
  display: table-row;
}
.myTable a span {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 2px; /* this line not really needed */
}
```

Comment: If you want to show tabular data, _always_ use a table. Using a collection of divs and spans is semantically incorrect, will turn you content hard to read if you loss the CSS and inacessible for who uses a screen reader.

Answer (score 12):

The usual way is to assign some JavaScript to the `onClick` attribute of the `TR` element.

If you can't use JavaScript, then you must use a trick:

1. Add the same link to each `TD` of the same row (the link must be the outermost element in the cell).
2. Turn links into block elements: `a { display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; }`

The latter will force the link to fill the whole cell so clicking anywhere will invoke the link.

Answer (score 7):

Answer from sirwilliam fits me best. I improved the Javascript with support for hotkey Ctrl + LeftClick (opens page in new tab). Event `ctrlKey` is used by PC's, `metaKey` by Mac.

**Javascript**

```
$('body').on('mousedown', 'tr[url]', function(e){
    var click = e.which;
    var url = $(this).attr('url');
    if(url){
        if(click == 2 || (click == 1 && (e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey))){
            window.open(url, '_blank');
            window.focus();
        }
        else if(click == 1){
            window.location.href = url;
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

**Example**

http://jsfiddle.net/vlastislavnovak/oaqo2kgs/

Comment: Good. Ctrl + LeftClick doesn't break UIX

Comment: Still losing 'right click -> open in a new tab' or 'open in a new window'

Answer (score 6):

You can't wrap a `<td>` element with an `<a>` tag, but you can accomplish similar functionality by using the `onclick` event to call a function. An example is found [here](http://imar.spaanjaars.com/QuickDocId.aspx?quickdoc=312), something like this function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function DoNav(url)
{
   document.location.href = url;
}
</script>
```

And add it to your table like this:

```
<tr onclick="DoNav('http://stackoverflow.com/')"><td></td></tr>
```

Comment: One of the problems with using onClick for this kind of purpose is users can no longer use the middle mouse button or control-click to open links in a new tab (which can be really frustrating for those of us who love opening links that way).  One other side note, there's no reason to complicate things by creating a function that only does one simple command.  If you're going to do this, just put "document.location.href=..." directly in the onclick attribute.

Answer (score 4):

I know this question is already answered but I still don't like any solution on this page. For the people who use JQuery I made a final solution which enables you to give the table row almost the same behaviour as the `<a>` tag.

This is my solution:

**jQuery** *You can add this for example to a standard included javascript file*

```
$('body').on('mousedown', 'tr[url]', function(e){
    var click = e.which;
    var url = $(this).attr('url');
    if(url){
        if(click == 1){
            window.location.href = url;
        }
        else if(click == 2){
            window.open(url, '_blank');
            window.focus();
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

**HTML** *Now you can use this on any `<tr>` element inside your HTML*

```
<tr url="example.com">
    <td>value</td>
    <td>value</td>
    <td>value</td>
<tr>
```

Comment: So close to pure js. `document.querySelector('tr[url]').addEventListener("mousedown", function(e){
    var click = e.which;
    var url = this.getAttribute("url");
    if(url){
        if(click == 1){
            window.location.href = url;
        }
        else if(click == 2){
            window.open(url, '_blank');
            window.focus();
        }
        return true;
    }
});`

Comment: In 2014 that was not available in [vanilla js](http://vanilla-js.com/), you spoiled brat ;P.

Answer (score 2):

When i want simulate a `<tr>` with a link but respecting the html standards, I do this.

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr class="trLink">
        <td>
            <a href="#">Something</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
tr.trLink {
    cursor: pointer;
}
tr.trLink:hover {
   /*TR-HOVER-STYLES*/
}

tr.trLink a{
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
tr.trLink:hover a{
   /*LINK-HOVER-STYLES*/
}
```

In this way, when someone go with his mouse on a TR, all the row (and this links) gets the hover style and he can't see that there are multiple links.

Hope can help someone.

Fiddle [HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/g6qctpwt/)

Answer (score 1):

This saves you having to duplicate the link in the tr - just fish it out of the first a.

```
$(".link-first-found").click(function() {
 var href;
href = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
if (href !== "") {
return document.location = href;
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Style
  .trlink {
    color:blue;
  }
  .trlink:hover {
    color:red;
  }

<tr class="trlink" onclick="function to navigate to a page goes here">
<td>linktext</td>
</tr>
```

Something along these lines perhaps?  Though it does use JS, but that's only way to make a row (tr) clickable.

Unless you have a single cell with an anchor tag that fills the entire cell.

And then, you shouldn't be using a table anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

After reading this thread and some others I came up with the following solution in javascript:

```
function trs_makelinks(trs) {
    for (var i = 0; i < trs.length; ++i) {
        if (trs[i].getAttribute("href") != undefined) {
            var tr = trs[i];
            tr.onclick = function () { window.location.href = this.getAttribute("href"); };
            tr.onkeydown = function (e) {
                var e = e || window.event;
                if ((e.keyCode === 13) || (e.keyCode === 32)) {
                    e.preventDefault ? e.preventDefault() : (e.returnValue = false);
                    this.click();
                }
            };
            tr.role = "button";
            tr.tabIndex = 0;
            tr.style.cursor = "pointer";
        }
    }
}

/* It could be adapted for other tags */
trs_makelinks(document.getElementsByTagName("tr"));
trs_makelinks(document.getElementsByTagName("td"));
trs_makelinks(document.getElementsByTagName("th"));
```

To use it put the href in tr/td/th that you desire to be clickable like: `<tr href="http://stackoverflow.com">`.
And make sure the script above is executed after the tr element is created (by its placement or using event handlers).

<s>The downside is it won't totally make the TRs behave as links like with divs with `display: table;`, and they won't be keyboard-selectable or have status text.</s> Edit: I made keyboard navigation work by setting onkeydown, role and tabIndex, you could remove that part if only mouse is needed. They won't show the URL in statusbar on hovering though.

You can style specifically the link TRs with "tr[href]" CSS selector.

Answer (score 0):

I have another way. Especially if you need to post data using jQuery

```
$(document).on('click', '#tablename tbody tr', function()
{   
    var test="something";
    $.post("ajax/setvariable.php", {ID: this.id, TEST:test}, function(data){        
        window.location.href = "http://somepage";
    });
});
```

Set variable sets up variables in SESSIONS which the page you are going to can read and act upon.

I would really like a way of posting straight to a window location, but I do not think it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for this. You can change the hover icon by assigning a CSS class to the  row like:

```
<tr class="pointer" onclick="document.location = 'links.html';">
```

and the CSS looks like:

```
<style>
    .pointer { cursor: pointer; }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

This method is here to give you a choice. Old css trick: filling the parent with position absolute.

```html
<table>
<tr style=position:relative>
<td><a href=# style=position:absolute;inset:0></a>some
<td>cells
<td>in
<td>a row
</table>
```

- `inset:0` is a shorthand for `top:0;right:0;bottom:0;left:0`
- we put `<a>` inside first `<td>` because this is a good chance to keep validity: only `<td>` can be a child of `<tr>`. But you can place it anywhere in the table and it will work.

Answer (score -2):

Can you add an A tag to the row?

```
<tr><td>
<a href="./link.htm"></a>
</td></tr>
```

Is this what you're asking?

Comment: No , I need in clicking for all row-area.