# HTML Linking a whole table tbody with an anchor

Tags: html, html-table, anchor

I have the following code:

```
<tbody>
<tr class="listing_left">
    <td>Info Here</td>
</tr>
<tr class="listing_right">
    <td>Info Here</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

It is being pulled dynamically so that is for each product.  So if I have 20 products, it shows that code 20 different times for each product.

I need each of those to link to a specific link.  I tried wrapping the whole tbody in an anchor and that did not work.  I tried wrapping the individual tr's in an anchor and that did not work.

If I wrap each TD in an anchor then that will work but the anchor is only for the specific text, it doesn't expand to the entire TR, which I need.

Any suggestions?

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460958/html-table-row-like-a-link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you can only have anchor tag within the `td` tag so I would suggest that you change your layout so you use `divs` instead of `tables`

Then you can do something like this:

```
<div>
   <div class="listing_left">
       Info Here
   </div>
   <div class="listing_right">
       Info Here
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The only reason I went with tables is so I could get vertical-align:middle; to work!

Comment: Then you can use  display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle ;)