# struts2, jQuery plugin and browsers compatibility

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, firefox, struts2, compatibility

All my code works fine with IE10. But with firefox ver26.0 and Chrome ver34, when I click on a list element in the table nothing happen.

a piece of main jsp:

```
<sj:div href="%{#richiesteAjax}" preload="true" updateFreq="10000"/>
```

and the jsp called from it:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;" language="java"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/stile1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<%
    request.setAttribute("decorator", "none");
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache"); //HTTP 1.1
    response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); //HTTP 1.0
    response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0); //prevents caching at the proxy server
%>

<table class="LISTA_MENU" border="0" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="1"
    align="center" style="width: 90%;">
    <tr>
        <th width="3%" class="LISTA_MENU">Id Richiesta</th>
        <th width="12%" class="LISTA_MENU">Nome</th>
        <th width="12%" class="LISTA_MENU">Cognome</th>
        <th width="8%" class="LISTA_MENU">Data richiesta</th>
        <th width="5%" class="LISTA_MENU">Stato richiesta</th>
    </tr>

    <s:iterator value="listaRichieste" status="stat">

        <s:url action="autorizzazioneRichiesta.action" var="urlTag">
            <s:param name="id" value="idRichiesta"></s:param>
        </s:url>

        <s:a href="%{urlTag}">
            <tr style="cursor: hand; cursor: pointer;">
                <td width="3%" class="RIGHE_TABELLA"><s:property
                        value="idRichiesta" /></td>
                <td width="12%" class="RIGHE_TABELLA"><s:property
                        value="anagrafica.nome" /></td>
                <td width="12%" class="RIGHE_TABELLA"><s:property
                        value="anagrafica.cognome" /></td>
                <td width="8%" class="RIGHE_TABELLA"><s:date
                        name="dataInserimento" format="dd/MM/yyyy" /></td>
                <td width="5%" class="RIGHE_TABELLA"><s:property
                        value="stato.descrizione" /></td>
            </tr>
        </s:a>
    </s:iterator>
</table>
```

What is it wrong?

Comment: Sorry are you using the Struts2 jQuery Plugin? There is no support for the attributes preload and updateFreq. Please take a look at the Wiki page. https://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/wiki/DivTag

Comment: Yes, but the preload and the updateFreq works fine with all the browser. Maybe you're talking about dojo plugin... The problem is another

Comment: He is the coder of Struts2-jQuery-Plugin - he is not talking about dojo :)

Comment: @jogep : `preload` no, but `updateFreq` is in your documentation :|

Comment: Uhm... if there's no support why is it working fine? :D

Comment: You are right updateFreq is supported and is working in latest showcase example. But preload is not supported

Comment: However my problem it's not this...! :) (and preload works too in my case for mysterious reason)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17147821/how-to-make-a-whole-row-in-a-table-clickable-as-a-link