# make a row clickable in html

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a table's rows clickable, by calling a controller (am using symfony) and i found  [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17147821/how-to-make-a-whole-row-in-a-table-clickable-as-a-link), but the problem i have is that even the titles of the row is clickable and leads me to an error, and the other problem is that when i customize the hover it's applied on all the rows even if i use a class or specified the style inside the `<tr>`

Here is my code

```
<table class="table table-hover ">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>N°</th>
      <th>Titre</th>
      <th>Date</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {% for key, rech in recherche %}
    <tr style="cursor: pointer;">
      <td><a href="{{ path('resultat',{'id':rech.id}) }}">{{ loop.index }}</a>
      </td>
      <td>{{ rech.titre | raw }}</td>
      <td>{{ rech.date | date('Y-m-d') |raw }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Thanks for your response.

Comment: this has nothing to do with the symfony2 tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this solution below.

**EDIT**
Make sure you add this reference in your header section

**EDIT**
put the js code in a file, and put this at the bottom of the page before the body close.

```
<script src="/path/filename.js">
```

Goes in the header

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/batcave/vrseu8L9/)

```
<table class="table table-hover ">
                                <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>N°</th>
                                    <th>Titre</th>
                                    <th>Date</th>
                                </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                {% for key, rech in recherche %}
                                    <tr data-href="{{ path('resultat',{'id':rech.id}) }}">
                                        <td>{{ loop.index }}</td>
                                        <td>{{ rech.titre | raw }}</td>
                                        <td>{{ rech.date | date('Y-m-d') |raw }}</td>
                                    </tr>
                                {% endfor %}
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
```

js

```
    $(function(){
      $(document).on('click', '[data-href]', function () {
        var url = $(this).data('href');
        if (url && url.length > 0) {
            document.location.href = url;
            return false;
        }
      });
    });
```

css

```
.table-hover tbody tr {
 background: #dcdcdc;
 pointer: cursor;
}
```

Comment: what kind of issue? @ADA15

Comment: the same of the first time

Comment: @ADA15 then something might be wrong with your url generating script? Try to add a hardcoded url instead to the `data-href` to see if it works. if you do like my solution above then only the content rows are getting the `data-href`, as that is only the thing in the foreach. The title rows `N°, Titre, Date` will not be clickable, they don't even have the `data-href`. It seems as your issue is also with css? check my modified answer.

Comment: I did exactly what you propose, but the row is not clickable and i can't really know what is the cause

Comment: @ADA15 you are most likley not referencing the jquery file, check my updated reply.

Comment: @ADA15 You can put the js function before closing the body, `</body>` I updated the answer with `<script>` tags surrounding it

Answer (score 0):

hello we just add the link for Jquery

```
<script src="../jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
        <thead style="display: none">
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Actions</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {% for project in projects %}


                <tr class="tablerowproject" data-href="{{ path('company_index') }}">

                    <td><i class="step fi-lightbulb" style="font-size: 60px; color: #FBFCF7 "></i></td>
                    <td>{{ project.name }}</td>
                    <td>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <a href="{{ path('project_show', { 'id': project.id }) }}">show</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="{{ path('project_edit', { 'id': project.id }) }}">edit</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </td>

                </tr>


        {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

and add this lines

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".tablerowproject").click(function() {
            window.document.location = $(this).data("href");
        });


    })
</script>
```

add in your file CSS add this

```
.tablerowproject {
    display: block;
    background-color: #345d71;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;

}
.tablerowproject:hover{
    background-color: #092636;
}
```

and this my result[image]