# Click a row and get directed to a page with a dynamic parameter in the URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, url, express

I have a row made in jade that looks like this `tr(data-href="http://localhost:3000/patient/" + patients[0].patient[g]["number"]).clickable-row` this outputs to the HTML as viewed in the console

**`<tr class="clickable-row" data-href="http://localhost:3000/patient/2">`**

when I click the row I get directed to http://localhost:3000/null

I tried changing `http://localhost:3000/patient/"` in the string to a lot of different things like `url:/patient/`. I got this click row to open new page method from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17147821/how-to-make-a-whole-row-in-a-table-clickable-as-a-link).

script:

```
$(".clickable-row").live("click",function(){
    window.document.location = $(this).data("href");
}) //using live because old version of jquery
```

app.js

```
app.get("/patient/:param1", function(req, res){
    res.send(req.params)
})
```

expected results: when user clicks a row they go to a page that has a url like localhost:3000/patient/2

EDIT: I think I have problem setting up the URL. I never had a good understanding of relative and absolute paths. and I had errors like this before when I needed to have a public folder to get static files.

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
window.document.location = $(this).data("href");
```

to

```
window.location.href = $(this).data("href");
```

Comment: @jackblank did you check what value you are getting for `$(this).data("href")`?

Comment: looks like I'm getting null..
right now i have the tr like ` tr(data-href="localhost:3000/patient/" + patients[0].patient[g]["number"]).clickable-row`

Comment: I'm using  jQuery JavaScript Library v1.4.2  EDIT I see  on https://api.jquery.com/data/#data-obj that `.data( obj )` was added in 1.4.3. am I using the `.data( obj )` form?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {

     $('.clickable-row').click(function () {

         window.location = $(this).attr("data-href");
     });
});
```

Comment: This gets me what I wanted :: `http://localhost:3000/patient/2` in the address box but my express app isn't working. I get a message from FF ''The address wasn't understood. can you look at my `app.get` I thought ` res.send(req.params)` or ` res.send(req.params.param1)` would work.

Comment: I think I'm not supposed to have `localhost:3000/patient/2` in the data-href in the HTML. Usually when you make a link you do <a href= "/login"></a> using express i get to `localhost:3000/login`. in the `a` tag I just showed  I didnt use `localhost:3000/` but in the html data-href i see `localhost:3000/patient/2`. maybe that's why FF is giving me the error

Comment: Ok this works: tr(data-href="patient/" + patients[0].patient[g]["number"]).clickable-row... THANK FOR YOUR HELP!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value using

```
$(this).attr('data-href')
```

**Full Example:**

(I show an `alert` just to show you the value. to redirect the user to this URL, use [`location.href`](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp))

```js
$('[data-href]').live('click', function(){
  alert($(this).attr('data-href'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr data-href="http://localhost:3000/patient/2">
    <td>Col 1</td>
    <td>Col 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: this gets me the right URL. but now I get an error `The address wasn't understood` from FF. I guess I have another problem using express

Comment: Ok this works: tr(data-href="patient/" + patients[0].patient[g]["number"]).clickable-row... THANK FOR YOUR HELP