# How to exclude <a> tags from click on a row in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I found my first answer in [how to make a whole row in a table clickable as a link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17147821/how-to-make-a-whole-row-in-a-table-clickable-as-a-link), but now there is a new question:

Using

```
<tbody>
    <tr class='clickable-row' data-href='url://link-for-first-row/'>
        <td>Blah Blah</td>
        <td>1234567</td>
        <td>£158,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='clickable-row' data-href='url://some-other-link/'>
        <td>More money</td>
        <td>1234567</td>
        <td><a href="url://somewhere-else-than-the-row">£800,000</a></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

and

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".clickable-row").click(function() {
        window.document.location = $(this).data("href");
    });
});
```

causes me to get in trouble with the last link to 'url://somewhere-else-than-the-row', especially, when I use a link with the method="delete" attribute, where the "Are you sure?" pops up, but either, I don't want to let the `window.location` to be run. So how can I exclude the click on the `<a>` element from the `window.document.location` reference?

Answer (score 2):

Events in javascript propagate up the dom hierarchy. You can read more about this here: [What is event bubbling and capturing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616694/what-is-event-bubbling-and-capturing)

As for your question, you may want to check out jquery's event.stopPropagation, to prevent the on click event from propogating up the dom and triggering more than 1 event. See http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_stoppropagation.asp

Code example:

```
<tbody>
<tr class='clickable' data-href='url://link-for-first-row/'>
    <td>Blah Blah</td>
    <td>1234567</td>
    <td>£158,000</td>
</tr>
<tr class='clickable' data-href='url://some-other-link/'>
    <td>More money</td>
    <td>1234567</td>
    <td><span class="clickable" data-href="url://somewhere-else-than-the-row">£800,000</span></td>
</tr>
```

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".clickable-row").click(function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        window.document.location = $(this).data("href");
    });
});
```

I've added 2 changes to your code:

- Instead of an `<a>` tag, I used a `<span>` tag with the "clickable" class
- To the event handler, I added a call to jquery's event.stopPropagation to make sure only the first handler will be called.

Answer (score 0):

Most *Events* bubble up the *DOM Tree*, the node you actually click on may not be the one the handler is set on.

- `this` in a handler (usually) refers to the node to which it is attached
- `event.target` (where `event` is the first arg of the handler) refers to the node clicked

Check if the target of the click is, or is a descendant of, an `<a>` before resolving the location.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".clickable-row").click(function (e) {
        if ($(e.target).closest('a').length) // if <a> or decendant of <a>
            return; // do nothing
        // otherwise
        window.document.location = $(this).data("href");
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks to both, I like this solution more, because I use ruby on rails, and i can simply use the link_to helper.  I use <%= link_to glyph('remove'), admin_person_path(admin_person), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %> for one of the links, so this solution is easyer to use.