# Clickable table row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this structure:

```js
jQuery('tr').bind('click', function() {
  var p = jQuery(this);
  p.children('td').children('a').click();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td width="88">A</td>
      <td width="88">B</td>
      <td width="88">C</td>
      <td width="88">D</td>
      <td width="88">E</td>
      <td width="88">F</td>
      <td width="88">G</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right">content A1</td>
      <td align="right">content B1</td>
      <td align="right">content C1</td>
      <td align="right">content D1</td>
      <td align="right">content E1</td>
      <td>content F1</td>
      <td>
        <a href="http://google.com" target="_blank">google</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right">content A2</td>
      <td align="right">content B2</td>
      <td align="right">content C2</td>
      <td align="right">content D2</td>
      <td align="right">content E2</td>
      <td>content F2</td>
      <td>
        <a href="http://facebook.com" target="_blank">facebook</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to programmatically call the click on `<a>` tag when I click on the table line.

Till now my code runs in a stack overflow error:

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

P.S. In my real code the `a` tag looks like this:

```
<a href="image_url" data-lightbox="image-1">
 <img src="thumb_image_url" />
</a>
```

and click on the image starts a lightbox effect.

Comment: I think your problem is that you don't cancel bubbling of the event in the `<a>` handler. This then bubbles up to the `<tr>` handler, which causes it to infinitely recurse. Try `return false;` in the `a.onclick` handler.

Comment: check this answer  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17147821/how-to-make-a-whole-row-in-a-table-clickable-as-a-link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the working snippet

```
jQuery('tr').bind('click', function() {
  var p = jQuery(this);
  p.find('td:last a')[0].click()
});
```

The issue in your code comes from the fact that

```
 p.children('td').children('a')
```

will return an array.

Answer (score 1):

I tried with pure javascript solution. It's working

```js
//jQuery('tr').bind('click', function() {
//  var p = jQuery(this);
//  p.children('td').children('a').click();
//});

var tr = document.querySelectorAll('tr');

if (tr) {
  for (var i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    var element = tr[i];
    element.addEventListener('click', clickedTr, false);
  }
}

function clickedTr() {
  var td_a = this.querySelectorAll('td a');
  if (td_a) {
    for (var i = 0; i < td_a.length; i++) {
      alert(td_a[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td width="88">A</td>
      <td width="88">B</td>
      <td width="88">C</td>
      <td width="88">D</td>
      <td width="88">E</td>
      <td width="88">F</td>
      <td width="88">G</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right">content A1</td>
      <td align="right">content B1</td>
      <td align="right">content C1</td>
      <td align="right">content D1</td>
      <td align="right">content E1</td>
      <td>content F1</td>
      <td>
        <a href="http://google.com" target="_blank">google</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right">content A2</td>
      <td align="right">content B2</td>
      <td align="right">content C2</td>
      <td align="right">content D2</td>
      <td align="right">content E2</td>
      <td>content F2</td>
      <td>
        <a href="http://facebook.com" target="_blank">facebook</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```