# Meteor 1.3 and bootstrap disregarding <td> and <tr> tags inside #each

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, meteor

I'm using Meteor (current on v1.3.4, regarding deployment reasons and compatibility with mup), and twbs:bootstrap. Here's a table I have in a template:

```
<div class = "table-responsive">
<table class="table table-hover table-condensed">
<thead>
<tr> 
    <th>Resource</th>
    <th>In Stock</th>
    {{#if stockFeatureShow 'price'}}
        <th>Price</th>
    {{/if}}
    {{#if stockFeatureShow 'group'}}
        <th>Group</th>
    {{/if}}
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    {{#each resources}}
        <a class= "viewPriceGraph" value = "{{itemNo}}">
            <tr>
                <td>
                        {{item}} 
                        {{#if coolCheck yearmod.kind}}
                            - cool right now!
                        {{/if}}
                        {{#if pollutedCheck yearmod.kind}}
                            - polluted right now :(
                        {{/if}}

                </td>
                <td>{{amount}}</td>
                {{#if stockFeatureShow 'price'}}
                    <td>{{price}}</td>
                {{/if}}
                {{#if stockFeatureShow 'group'}}
                    <td>{{groupName}}</td>
                {{/if}}
            </tr>
        </a>
    {{/each}}
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

I know this has worked a few months ago correctly, and I don't think I've made any changes since (maybe moved the meteor version ahead from 1.3 or some such?), but suddenly, the meteor rendering seems to disregard all my `<tr>` and `<td>` tags inside the {{#each}} segment.

[screenshot of table from running app, where all data from the each function has been stuffed into the first, one cell of the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1q9SB.png)

I'm pretty clueless about where to go from this. Any suggestions?

[EDIT: I just recalled that I added ensureindex queries on most of my collections, for different pairs of intersections of fields, i.e., field A & B, and field A, B, & C of collection 1, and so on. I can't fathom how that'd be causing this break, I did a bunch of db query checks from meteor mongo and the returned queries still appear to look correct.]

[EDIT 2: I should really have done this check before, but I now looked at the rendered HTML and it does have the `<td>` and `<tr>` tags. Safari manages to break the different `<tr>`-s into rows, but not the `<td>`-s.

[Screenshot of how the different pieces of data have separate `<td>`-s but they're all scrunched up together.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RIrYK.png)

This makes me assume the issue is with the twbs:bootstrap package, but I have no idea how to decipher where. The console doesn't tell me of any errors anywhere.]

[EDIT 3: It's not an issue with the entire bootstrap package, cause other tables are being rendered fine. It seems everything inside the anchor tag causes the table contents to break. It's mysterious to me cause this wasn't happening before, but I guess this is a much simpler problem to solve.]

Comment: Try moving the `<td>` tags outside the `{{#if ...}}` statements

Comment: @ChrisSatchell Ideally I don't want those columns/cells to exist  or take up space if I'm not showing those features on certain pages, that's why I've put the `<td>` tags inside the `#if` statements.
I tried that too, it still doesn't work.

Comment: Could you maybe show an HTML snippet showing that broken table? Just to see what the actual DOM looks like

Comment: Yeah, looks like there might be something in the data you're returning that is causing the DOM to break. An HTML snippet would be useful for debugging this.

Comment: @ChrisSatchell Added another screenshot with a new find, that the  html has the cell and row tags, but they're just not being spaced correctly. I assume this is bootstrap's fault. What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, wrapping a row or multiple cells of a table inside an anchor tag (sometimes) breaks the cell separation, and bootstrap/html strings them all together. Ideally, only the contents of the cell should be anchor-linked.

I used [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17147821/how-to-make-a-whole-row-in-a-table-clickable-as-a-link) to fix my code, and the table now works. Thanks for the help!