# TYPO3 <f:link.action> viewhelper that renders only the url (href) not the a tag

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x, viewhelper

I have the need in a fluid template to create a link for a complete table row, this syntax requires the following html code ([taken from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17147821/how-to-make-a-whole-row-in-a-table-clickable-as-a-link))
`<tr class="clickable-row" data-href="url://http://domain.com/index.php?...">` which I try to produce with an inline viewhelper annotation:

```
<tr class="clickable-row" data-href="url://{f:link.action(pageUid: settings.detailPid, absolute: 'TRUE', controller: 'Object', pluginName: 'Objects', action: 'detail', arguments: {object:item})}">
```

this wraps the link in an `<a tag>` that messes all up

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ViewHelper you are looking for is `<f:uri.action>`
https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/fluid/master/Uri/ActionViewHelper.html

Comment: Spot-on, that is a beginners error one makes one time only !! well done