# react use Link on entire tr failed

Tags: reactjs, react-router

```
<tbody>
                {map(items, item =>
                    <Link to={routeUrl(ROUTES.SOMEWHERE, item.id)}>
                    <tr key={item.id}>
                        <td>
                            {item.name}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            {item.country}
                        </td>
                        </tr>
                    </Link>
                )}
            </tbody>
```

This won't work, any clue why? I can put the Link component within the td but I want the entire row to be clickable.

Comment: That does not result in valid HTML, `tbody` tags may only contain `tr` tags, `tr` tags may only contain `td` or `th` tags, see [link](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_table.asp).

Comment: @ccKep where should I put my Link component then?

Comment: On the text (eg. inside the `td`) you want the link on. If you want the whole row to be clickable you really only have 2 options: a) JS on-click events triggering a `window.location` change ([example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17147821/how-to-make-a-whole-row-in-a-table-clickable-as-a-link)) b) Style your `a` tags so they look like a table row and don't use an HTML `<table>` at all.

Comment: You can add links to each cell, you can also add a click handler to the tr that calls click() on one of those links in the cells

Comment: @cckep no need to call window.location yourself, you can have the click handler for the tr call click on one of the links in the cells

Comment: @JuanMendes I was thinking about something along the line of (jquery-style) `<tr data-href="...">` and `window.location.href = $(this).data("href")` in an on-click handler - although your idea works aswell!

Comment: @cckep it's because Link has special behavior to work with the router, but I may be overthinking it. The OP has two good leads now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to JSX rules, a `Link` component should contain only a string and not another component. Instead of using `Link` you can add `onClick` method on `tr` component and then you can define the route where you want to go in the body of `onClick`.