# How to make the whole row clickable?

Tags: javascript, html, routes, vue.js

I am using Vue and have:

```
<tr v-for="(blabla, index) in data">
  <td>{{ blabla.id }}</td>
  <td>{{ blabla.username }}</td>
  <td>{{ blabla.name }}</td>
  <td>
    <router-link 
      :to="{ name: 'name', params: { blabla: blabla.id } }"
      class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--accent"
    >
      Details
    </router-link>                     
  </td>                    
</tr>
```

How can I make the whole row clickable, not just the button that has the router link?

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17147821/how-to-make-a-whole-row-in-a-table-clickable-as-a-link   ?

Comment: No, i have already seen this link

Comment: But, are you using any JS lib, like JQuery? Or are you using JS at all?

Comment: I am using Vuejs, and when i put this like in the link you have send all mdl table design broke and i just cant fix it :/

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Add a click listener on the `tr` and [change the route programmatically](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/navigation.html):

```
<tr v-for="(blabla, index) in data" @click="goToBlabla(blabla.id)">
  <td>{{ blabla.id }}</td>
  <td>{{ blabla.username }}</td>
  <td>{{ blabla.name }}</td>
  <td>
    <a class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--accent">
      Details
    </a>                     
  </td>                    
</tr>
```

```javascript
methods: {
  goToBlabla(id) {
    this.$router.push({ name: 'name', params: { blabla: id } });
  }
}
```

---

Alternately, you could put the `v-for` on a `<router-link>` with the `tag` property set to `tr`:

```
<router-link 
  v-for="(blabla, index) in data" 
  :to="{ name: 'name', params: { blabla: blabla.id } }"
  tag="tr"
>
  <td>{{ blabla.id }}</td>
  <td>{{ blabla.username }}</td>
  <td>{{ blabla.name }}</td>
  <td>
    <a class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--accent">
      Details
    </a>                     
  </td>                    
</router-link>
```

Specifying the tag as `tr` will render the component as a `tr` element.

Comment: woow, i am a begginer in vuejs, and don't even know that that exists!! Many many thanks!! I will research more for it.

Comment: Adding a `tag` property to your `<router-link>` does not make it clickable, it only enables you to apply the `active` class to the outer element of your `<a>` tag ([documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#router-link)).

Comment: tag property has been deprecated in vue router 4 insted use `custom` tag

Comment: @VaibhavPhutane how should it be? `custom` is for many usages