# making an image as a link to aother page

Tags: javascript, html

I am fetching data from firebase realtime database and displaying it in form of table.I want to make a row in a table as a link to another page but when i am adding  tag inside script tag its not working and it is showing an error.

code
**JS**

```
<script>
    var fbRef = firebase.database().ref().child("Sell_Products");
fbRef.on("child_added", snap => {
    var name = snap.child("name").val();
    var price = snap.child("price").val();
    var category = snap.child("category").val();
    var description = snap.child("description").val();
    var image = snap.child("image").val();
    $("#ex-table").append("<tr><td><a href="auction.html">/*here it is showing error "missing ) after argument list"*/<img src=" + image + "/img></a></td><td>" + name + "</td><td>" + price + "</td><td>" + category + "</td><td>" + description + "</td></tr>" );
});
```

How to solve this error and if this process is wrong then how can i make an image as link to another page.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In your href you used double quote ("). As your string start with double quote so whenever you use double quote it means end of the string. You have to concat it with + or use single quote.

`$("#ex-table").append("<tr><td><a href='auction.html'><img src='" + image + "'/></a></td><td>" + name + "</td><td>" + price + "</td><td>" + category + "</td><td>" + description + "</td></tr>" );`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. One more question if i want to make entire row as a link to another page what should i do?

Comment: What's wrong with:  `$("#ex-table").append("<tr><td><a href=auction.html><img src=" + image + "</img></a></td><td>" + name + "</td><td>" + price + "</td><td>" + category + "</td><td>" + description + "</td></tr>" );`

Comment: @Mamun you need to add href value as string. <a href=auction.html></a> here auction.html isn't a valid string.

Comment: @AbhishekKumar I think https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17147821/how-to-make-a-whole-row-in-a-table-clickable-as-a-link?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa will be helpful for you.

Comment: Then `("<tr><td><a href='auction.html'><img src="......` is enough.. though I think the previous code will form the valid HTML....you can do a quick check...