# How to put a React Router Link on a Material UI TableRow

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, react-router-dom

I am trying to put a `Link` component form **React Router Dom** on my **Material UI TableRow** element

```
<TableRow component={Link as any} to={`/company/${company.id}`} className="clt-row" key={company.id}>
```

But I keep getting the folliwng error

```
Property 'to' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & TableRowProps & { children?: ReactNode; }'.  TS2769
```

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: So the Link is just being used without any `to` prop or anything?

Comment: @minus.273 No I am using the `to` prop but the `TableRow` element is throwing an error.

Comment: Yes, but you are using it as a prop for the `TableRow` component, where it actually should go as a prop to the `Link` component. Because in the TableRow API i don't see any `to` prop

Comment: @minus.273 I see other answers that are saying to implement it that way. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50691049/how-to-add-link-react-router-per-each-material-ui-tablerow

Comment: @AmenRa You mean the post with 0 accepted answers? What version of Material-UI are you using? [v4](https://material-ui.com/api/table-row/#props) looks like it should handle it. All extra props are passed to the root element. Is the alias messing with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rows need cells. The `component` prop represents the component to be used for the root node of the row. It defaults to just a `tr` but could be any component that renders a `tr` as a root node.

```
<TableRow>
    <TableCell colSpan={3}> // or however many columns are in your table
        <Link to={`/company/${company.id}`} className="clt-row" key={company.id} />
    </TableCell>
</TableRow>
```

Comment: I need to have the whole row to be clickable to go to another component. Not just a `TableCell`

Comment: There is a `colSpan` prop that can make a cell span as many columns as you like.