# How to add a column link to material-ui table and redirect to summary detail page using column link id

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, report, material-table, drilldown

I am working Material-UI tables, such as the following [basic table](https://material-ui.com/components/tables/#basic-table) here but I have added an id column at the beginning.

Assuming I have this basic table example at the route `localhost:3000/basic-table` within my React app, how can I take the below code and make the `<tableCell>{row.id}</tableCell>` into a `<a href link>` which will allow the user to click on this `{row.id}` column and then present the user with a new screen, where I can take this id and show more data about it?

I will also need a means of returning back to the main page report, i.e. parent page.

What I am trying to achieve is basically from the main parent report, a user can click on a row id, which would then present the user with a detailed report based on that id, i.e. like a drill-down report.

From the doco, I can't find any examples where I can achieve this as unsure how to add a column link.

Can anyone help with this or point me to an example.

```
      {rows.map((row) => (
        <TableRow key={row.id}>
          <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
            {row.id}
          </TableCell>
          <TableCell align="right">{row.name}</TableCell>
          <TableCell align="right">{row.calories}</TableCell>
          <TableCell align="right">{row.fat}</TableCell>
          <TableCell align="right">{row.carbs}</TableCell>
          <TableCell align="right">{row.protein}</TableCell>
        </TableRow>
      ))}
```

Comment: For other people, the below answer is fine but I ended up using the following code            <TableCell key={column.id} align={column.align}>
                  <Link
                    to={`/elsewhere/${row.id}`}
                    style={{ textDecoration: 'underline', color: 'black' }}
                  >
                    {value}
                  </Link>
             </TableCell> to achieve my requirement. This is from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50691049/how-to-add-link-react-router-per-each-material-ui-tablerow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use history API

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

const YourComponent = () => {
...
const history = useHistory();
return {
    ...
    rows.map((row) => (
        <TableRow key={row.id} onClick={() => history.push(yourLocation)}>
          <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
            {row.id}
          </TableCell>
          <TableCell align="right">{row.name}</TableCell>
          <TableCell align="right">{row.calories}</TableCell>
          <TableCell align="right">{row.fat}</TableCell>
          <TableCell align="right">{row.carbs}</TableCell>
          <TableCell align="right">{row.protein}</TableCell>
        </TableRow>
      ))}
}
```

Comment: I actually just want a link on the `{row.id}` column alone and when the user clicks on this id column link, how can I pass this id value to say `localhost:3000/basic-table/summary?id=5? With your `push(yourLocation)` - does this need to be a route I need to create in my App.js?

Comment: You can push any route.
`history.push('/basic-table/summary?id=${row.id}')`

Comment: You can use history API anywhere in your code to navigate to desired page