# How can i put an href link in my foreach statement?

Tags: php, foreach, hyperlink

For starters i am fairly new at this.
I am trying to figure out how to a href link my row 'inspection_files' and i have tried just about everything. Is there anybody who could help me?

```
<?php
$i = 0;
foreach ($result as $r) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $r['last_inspection'] . "</td><td>" . strtolower(trim(($r['inspected_by_company']))) . "</td><td>" . strtolower(trim($r['inspection_files'])) . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";

    $i++;
}
?>
```

Comment: A little more information and a little clearer would be nice but I think this is what you are looking for. - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17147821/how-to-make-a-whole-row-in-a-table-clickable-as-a-link

Comment: This is basic HTML (101). An `<a href>` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a

Answer (score -1):

Hey you can directly use `<a>` tag inside the `<td>`, just like below

```
echo "<td>" . $r['last_inspection'] . "</td><td>" . strtolower(trim(($r['inspected_by_company']))) . "</td><td><a href='" . strtolower(trim($r['inspection_files'])) . "'>" . strtolower(trim($r['inspection_files'])) . "</a></td>";
```

I hope `$r['inspection_files']` this is your URL if this is not your redirect URL then just replace with your actual URL.

Comment: Not my downvote here, but I edited your answer to use ticks around (HTML) markup elements. Go into edit mode to see what I did. Edit: Not sure why you got a downvote though. Maybe the person can elaborate on it?