# streteched-link bootstrap utilities doesn't work in Chrome

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome

It seems that the [stretched-link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/stretched-link/) in Bootstrap doesn't work for `<tr>`.

It is OK for Firefox but not for Chrome, which seems to ignore `position:relative` for certain tag, like `tr`.

For example : https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-bas-t1zoi

The link for the 2nd row is not "stopped" and all the body is considered to be the target, so a click on any part of the page will click the 2nd link.

I'm surprised that Bootstrap doc doesn't mention this big limitation.

Have you any solution for that?

Comment: For future readers, I have opted for using `onClick` on tr tag. It is not as good as a link, since I don't have the URL of the page in the status bar when the mouse is over but it is acceptable.

Comment: +1. I was inspired with [this `onclick` answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17147876/5601069) and feel the same about it.

Comment: Thanks for the link. This answer is useful too : https://stackoverflow.com/a/57591579/2728710 and gave an example of stretched-link which works for Chrome + Firefox but not Safari.