# Wordpress Post Loop output out of order (PHP)

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm using a table to display post information for layout reasons. Ideally each row should be a link to the post, but when I load the page there is a list of all links Before the table begins. I have encountered similar issues before but I still don't have an understanding of exatly why this behaviour occurs. Code is below. Any explanation and best practice to avoid this issue appreciated.

```
<table>
<?php while(have_posts()): the_post(); ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
        <tr>
            <td><?php the_title();?></td>
            <td><?php get_the_tags();?></td>
            <td><?php the_date(); ?></td>
        </tr>
    </a>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</table>
```

Comment: You can't put a `tr` inside of an `a` element, that is invalid table structure. If you want the row to be clickable, you could try one of [these solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17147821/how-to-make-a-whole-row-in-a-table-clickable-as-a-link).

Comment: Just found this exact post, working through it, cheers!